# Processing text images using the OpenCV library

Tags: python, opencv

Please help me! "I have a problem as follows."

Using only the OpenCV library, perform the task of processing the following input: at least 5 images containing various text content, each image having at least 100 words (including uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and digits). The following six lowercase letters must appear in each image: a, b, c, d, e, f. Output: for each image, draw rectangular frames around the 6 specified letters mentioned in the input, each with a different color. The process of drawing rectangular frames should be automated and not done manually.

I don't know how to solve the problem above using only the OpenCV library

Comment: What  is the image look like? Just one image will do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's homework with no effort put into solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Getting Text out of images

Try this [link](https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/) tutorial

Step 2 : Iterate through the extracted results and create the function to get your output (The six lowercase letters you have mentioned)
You can use regular expressions to create your function to filter out your desired string. Check [this](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-str-compare/) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Step 3 : You can draw rectangles based on the detected contours. Check this [link](https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/05/25/tesseract-ocr-text-localization-and-detection/) and you can plot with different colors

The solution will be automatic. Hope this will be helpful as you have not given proper examples of your input or output image I am not able to answer any further.